# How to save multiple pandas plots in one PDF

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am working on this code. My plots are being generated, but they are not getting saved in 1 pdf file.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
k = mno['LocationID'].unique()       
with PdfPages('demo_try1.pdf') as pdf:
     
     fig = plt.figure(figsize=(25,12))
     for i in range(mno['LocationID'].nunique()):
         pqr = mno[mno.LocationID == k[i]]
         figure = pqr.plot(x="Date", y="Quantity").get_figure()
         pdf.savefig(figure)
         plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [25,12]
         plt.suptitle("Sales plot for LocationID: {} ".format(pqr['LocationID'].iloc[i]), fontsize=20)
         plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=18)
         plt.ylabel('Quantity', fontsize=18)
         plt.show()
     pdf.savefig(fig)
```

Comment: You may need to `plt.close()` on a page-by-page basis. See [this page](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/misc/multipage_pdf.html).

Comment: Thankyou so much. It worked.